# Put several values from inside a string into an array

Tags: javascript

A Fetch that i do returns this (everything in vanilla js):

[image: Fetch return]

now, i cant loop through it since it isn't an array, it's an object.
what i did is stringify the result so i get:

```
{"Nurture":43,"Regrowth":31,"Music":37,"Blades":12,"Blunt":1}
```

What i want is put all values between " " in an array and all numbers in another array.  or 1 nested array would also be fine.

Comment: Rather than stringifying your object, leave it as an object, and use `Object.keys()` to get the keys (ie: things between the double-quotes), and `Object.values()` to get your numbers. Not sure what you mean by one nested array, but maybe `Object.entries()` would work for that output.

Comment: ```Object.values(specializationsObj)``` Now you can get all the values

Comment: Yes! i figured out how it works Object.keys(out[0].specializations) and similar with values() will do it for me, thanks for the lightning fast responses